# System performance deteriorated after last Ubuntu kernel update

Tags: 18.04, graphics, performance

Just yesterday I installed the last kernel update using Software Updater. Running flightgear now deteriorates the whole system performance. The issue disappears returning to the previous kernel 5.3.0-45.
After the update I ended up with

```
    Linux HP 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Command

```
    cat /var/log/dpkg.log
```

results in

```
2020-04-06 21:08:43 startup archives unpack
2020-04-06 21:08:44 install linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:44 status half-installed linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:45 status unpacked linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:45 status unpacked linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:45 install linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:45 status half-installed linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:46 status unpacked linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:46 status unpacked linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:46 install linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:46 status half-installed linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:49 upgrade linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status half-configured linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status half-installed linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status half-installed linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:49 upgrade linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status half-configured linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status half-installed linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status half-installed linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status unpacked linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:49 install linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all <none> 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:49 status half-installed linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:51 status unpacked linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:51 status unpacked linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:51 install linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 <none> 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:51 status half-installed linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status unpacked linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status unpacked linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:52 upgrade linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status half-configured linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status unpacked linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status half-installed linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status half-installed linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status unpacked linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status unpacked linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:52 upgrade linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-91.92 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status half-configured linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-91.92
2020-04-06 21:08:52 status unpacked linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-91.92
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-installed linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-91.92
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-installed linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-91.92
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-06 21:08:53 upgrade linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-configured linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-installed linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-installed linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.45.101
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:08:53 startup packages configure
2020-04-06 21:08:53 configure linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1 <none>
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-configured linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status installed linux-modules-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:53 configure linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1 <none>
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-configured linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status installed linux-headers-5.3.0-46:all 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:53 configure linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-96.97 <none>
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-configured linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status installed linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-06 21:08:53 configure linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1 <none>
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status unpacked linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:53 status half-configured linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:54 status installed linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:54 status triggers-pending linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:54 configure linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1 <none>
2020-04-06 21:08:54 status unpacked linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:54 status half-configured linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:54 status installed linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:54 configure linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1 <none>
2020-04-06 21:08:54 status unpacked linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:08:54 status half-configured linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status installed linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:09:45 configure linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102 <none>
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status unpacked linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status half-configured linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status installed linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 configure linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102 <none>
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status unpacked linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status half-configured linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status installed linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 configure linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102 <none>
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status unpacked linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status half-configured linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status installed linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 configure linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102 <none>
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status unpacked linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status half-configured linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status installed linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64 5.3.0.46.102
2020-04-06 21:09:45 trigproc linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1 <none>
2020-04-06 21:09:45 status half-configured linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
2020-04-06 21:10:33 status installed linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic:amd64 5.3.0-46.38~18.04.1
```

After that update, whenever I run Flightgear the whole system appears to freeze after a number of seconds for about 5 seconds each time.

Command
`top`
doesn't show any extreme suspicious usage beside Xorg taking 3% of CPU from time to time when Flightgear is not running, but when it's running, it's impossible to identify the troublemaker as the whole of the system freezes for a short time and when it comes back `top` shows its statistics in a rapid sequence impossible to read.

Any idea what the source of the problem could be or how to better diagnose it?
Thanks for any help.

EDIT
Before running flightgear

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        2,3G        1,8G        427M        3,6G        4,7G
Swap:          4,0G          0B        4,0G
```

While running flightgear

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        4,2G        452M        618M        3,0G        2,6G
Swap:          4,0G        218M        3,8G
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Temporarily try this... in `terminal`... `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`... if that doesn't improve things, set it back to =60. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, that appears to have improved things a bit, but not yet enough. I tried rebooting, setting it again, and running flightgear so to make sure it started afresh. I even tried with swappiness 90 and then 100. No apparent difference respect to 80.

Comment: Try booting to the prior kernel... just to eliminate that as a factor.

Comment: @heynnema, It works flawlessly
```Linux HP 5.3.0-45-generic #37~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 15:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux```

Comment: Well, stick with that until they come out with a newer kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I created an account just to say that I have the exact same issue with Flightgear and this new update which I installed about 24 hours ago. It is definitely related to the update to : `linux-image-5.3.0-46-generic` because if I reboot the machine, go to the grub menu and select the previous kernel : `linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic`, everything goes back to normal and I can play Flightgear.

Answer (score 1):

I also see degraded graphics performance (on Ubuntu 18.04), but mostly when running Java programs (I don't really use my computer for gaming).  I'm wondering whether it is specific to Radeon graphics cards because I don't see poor performance on another machine (without Radeon graphics) with the same kernel (but a different version of Ubuntu: 19.10).  Here is some output on the machine that exhibits the slow Java graphics:

> lspci | grep VGA
>   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev 83)

Reverting back to 5.3.0-45-generic solves the problem.

Comment: In my case it's Intel
```00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly now with the most recent kernel upgrade by Ubuntu

```
Linux HP 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```